# cpp-httplib https server not working on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, server, openssl

I am trying to create a HTTPS Server running on linux with cpp-httplib in C++. (https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib)
Everything worked when I used Windows. But on linux only the HTTP Server works.
It seems like the HTTPS Server does not open a port which I do not understand...
When typing: sudo netstat -tuplen   in Terminal the expected port 8080 only shows up when running the HTTP Server not when running the HTTPS Server.
My firewall also seems to be inactive: sudo ufw status   gives  Status: inactive
Maybe I have linked something wrong, but everything seems to run fine.
I am new to C++ and Linux, so it is likely I have just made a silly mistake.
I just run this code in Clion if that matters..

this is the Code for the HTTP Server (working and running as expected):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "./httplib.h"

int main(void) {
    httplib::Server svr;

    svr.Get("/hi", [](const auto&, auto& res) {
        res.set_content("This is a test response", "text/plain");
    });

    std::cout << "start server..." << std::endl;
    svr.listen("192.158.1.38", 8080);


    std::cin.get();
}
```

this is the Code for the HTTPS Server (running but not opening a port):

```
#pragma comment (lib, "crypt32")

#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT
#include <iostream>
#include "./httplib.h"


// These are shown by Clion that they are not used...
#include </usr/include/openssl/conf.h>
#include </usr/include/openssl/evp.h>
#include </usr/include/openssl/err.h>

int main(void) {

    /// behind svr there have to be keys can not be self signed keys like in 
    httplib::SSLServer svr("./keys/localhost.crt", "./keys/localhost.key");


    svr.Get("/hi", [](const auto&, auto& res) {
        res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.set_content("This is a test response", "text/plain");

    });



    std::cout << "start server..." << std::endl;
    svr.listen("192.158.1.38", 8080);


    std::cin.get();

}
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(TLS_Server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(TLS_Server main.cpp)


find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)


find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(TLS_Server PRIVATE OpenSSL::SSL PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

Comment: Something to check is the location of the SSL certs and whether your application is finding them. You need to get the result codes and see what the library is telling you is the problem. See the Error Code section of the README.md file in the GitHub repository you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have now given the absolute path to the certs and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as mentioned in the comments the problem was that the certs could not be found. I have given the absolute path for now and it works fine.
Thanks!

PS: As I said: "probably a silly mistake"..

Comment: Happy to hear it worked out. How did you determine that the problem was the certs could not be found? Could you provide more details about how you were able to figure that out?

Comment: I just gave the global path of the certs after I read your comment and it worked. The port opened and I connected via a Browser to the server. I did not determine the problem by logging Error Messages.